# Does disabling the "Allow from Unknown Sources" Option in the Android settings prevent automatic malware download/installation?

Tags: android, security, malware, phishing

So the other day I was thinking about app distribution and I came across this setting in the Android settings "Allow Unknown sources". I have read a few articles about it, but none seem to discuss how secure this feature exactly is.

I was wondering if disabling this option (let's say for every listed app) can prevent the automatic download and installation of malicious software from phishing links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't prevent download.  It prevents install.  So you can't install an app through any means other than adb or the play store unless you enable that option.

Comment: Let's say the malware was to download on to your phone, would this option prevent the installation of the malware or is the download enough for the malware to be active ?

Comment: Depends on the malware.  If its an app, it needs to be installed or run.  If it's a zero day vulnerability in the reader (say someone finds a bug that causes a buffer overflow in chrome when viewing images) then opening it is enough.